# Variance of difference in mean estimator for Average Treatment Effects

Tags: variance, causality, treatment-effect

Consider $n$ Patients each of whom is treated with probability $p$ and given control with $1-p$ independent of everything else. Let $W_i$ be $1$ if the patient $i$ is treated and $0$ otherwise.

Let $Y_i$ be the response observed from patient $i$. We make the standard assumption of SUTVA, ie. $Y_i$ only depends on if the patient was treated or not, $Y_i = Y_i(W_i)$. We also assume that $W_i$ is independent of $\{Y_i(0), Y_i(1)\}$. And that $\{Y_i(0), Y_i(1)\}_{i=1}^n$ are iid across all patients.

Define $n_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n W_i$, and  $n_0 =n - n_1$. We define the difference of means estimator as

$$ \tau_{DM} = \frac{1}{n_1} \sum_{i=1}^n W_iY_i -  \frac{1}{n_0} \sum_{i=1}^n (1-W_i)Y_i$$

It is easy to see using tower law of expectations  that

$$\mathbb{E}  [\tau_{DM} ]= \mathbb{E}   [Y(1)] - \mathbb{E}  [Y(0)]$$

Similarly using law of total variance gives me that,

$$\text{Var}  [\tau_{DM} ]= \frac{p}{n} \text{Var}  [Y(1) ] +  \frac{1-p}{n} \text{Var}  [Y(0) ] + \frac{p(1-p)}{n} \left( \mathbb{E}   [Y(1)] - \mathbb{E}  [Y(0)]\right)^2$$

However, these [lecture notes](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eswager/stats361.pdf) (page 3, eq 1.4) say that,

$$\text{Var}  [\tau_{DM} ]= \frac{1}{n_1} \text{Var}  [Y(1) ] +  \frac{1}{n_0} \text{Var}  [Y(0) ] $$

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/527099/321865

Comment: It does! Thanks!