# The Variance of difference in means estimator

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, causality

I found [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/531936/variance-of-difference-in-mean-estimator-for-average-treatment-effects) unanswered so let me ask the same question with more details. (The link provided is not satisfactory to me.)

Suppose a binary treatment with $P(W_i=1)=p$ and $P(W_i=0)=1-p$. All experimental units are iid. Let $Y_i(0)$ and $Y_i(1)$ denote the potential outcomes for $W_i=0,1$ respectively. We are interested in PATE, $E[Y_i(1)-Y_i(0)]$ and use the difference-in-means estimator $\hat{\tau}=1/N_1\sum W_iY_i - 1/N_0\sum (1-W_i)Y_i$.

By the law of total variance, we have
\begin{align*}
    Var[W_iY_i] &= Var[E[W_iY_i \mid W_i]] + E[Var[W_iY_i \mid W_i]] \\
    & = Var[W_iE[Y_i \mid W_i]] + E[W_i^2Var[Y_i \mid W_i]] \\
    & = Var[W_iE[Y_i(W_i)]] + E[W_i^2Var[Y_i(W_i)]] \\
    & = p(1-p)\mu_1^{2} + p\sigma_1^{2}.
\end{align*}
Similarly, we have
\begin{align*}
    Var[(1-W_i)Y_i] &=  p(1-p)\mu_0^{2} + (1-p)\sigma_0^{2}
\end{align*}
where
$\mu_w^{2}= E[Y_i(w)]$ and $\sigma_w^{2}= Var[Y_i(w)]$ for $w=0,1$ respectively.

But these variance does not get me the variance given in [this lecture note](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eswager/stats361.pdf) (page 3, eq 1.4)
What am I doing wrong here?

[UPDATE]
[This thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/526984/how-to-derive-the-form-of-the-central-limit-theorem-for-the-difference-in-means/527099#527099) is trying to address my issue but I am not 100% convinced. Specifically, I could not figure out the last part of the decomposition of $\hat{\tau}$.

\begin{align*}
    \tau = 1/n \sum (\frac{Z_iY_i}{K}-\frac{(1-Z_i)Y_i}{1-K})= 1/n \sum (\frac{Y_i(1)}{K}-\frac{Y_i(0)}{1-K}).
\end{align*}
It does not seem like the last equation holds because $Y_i$ is an observed outcome, and under the SUTVA, the observed outcome is represented as $Y_i = Z_iY_i(1)+(1-Z_i)Y_i(0)$, which is also mentioned by the guy who asked that question.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The question you reference is answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/526984/how-to-derive-the-form-of-the-central-limit-theorem-for-the-difference-in-means/527099#527099.  Does that address your issues?

Comment: Thank you for your comment but unfortunately no. I will update the question with some more details.

Comment: I suspect you might be overlooking the fact that asymptotically the variance of $W_i/n$ plays no role in the variance of $\hat\tau,$  because it grows vanishingly small.

Comment: What I am saying is that $Z_iY_i$ is not equal to $Y(1)$ so the decomposition given in the link does not hold