# How does the variance of the difference in means estimator scale with n and the probability of treatment?

Tags: variance, inference, estimators

I found a similar question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/581605/the-variance-of-difference-in-means-estimator) but unanswered.

Given a binary treatment generated from a Bernoulli distribution with probability $p$ of success ($(_=1)=$, $(_=0)=1−$), how do I know how the error of the difference in means estimator scales with $p$ and $n$?

I know that writing the difference in means estimator as $̂=1/_1∑__−1/_0∑(1−_)_$, can derive its variance from the law of total variance and marginalizing as

$$Var(\hat{\tau}) = \frac{1}{n} \left( p \sigma_1  + (1 - p) \sigma_{0} +p(1-p) (\mu_1+  \mu_{0})^2\right),$$

where $\sigma_1, \sigma_{0}, \mu_1, \mu_{0}$ are the variance and mean of $Y | T = 1$ and $Y | T = 0$, respectively. Is this correct? If so, then I get that the variance of the estimator scales with $p/n$, is this right?

I am not sure whether this is the right way of modelling things.. I found [this derivation](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5d54a19a5a1edf0001ea677a/t/622ab2ae06e015231e73e814/1646965423144/Tom_Leavitt_var_diff_means_estimator.pdf) of the difference in means estimator variance but for complete random assignment (not Bernoulli trials) and I am not sure how to compare.